# Cannot get Python files to open in cmd

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd

I am new to programming, only two weeks in, and I am using Python 3.8. I am working my way through "Automate the Boring Stuff." One of the projects has us opening files in the cmd line and I cannot get .py files to open using cmd. When I only type python it gives me good info:It tells me this is Python 3.8.5 yadda yadda yadda. Then, if I try to type python hello.py it says 'invalid syntax.' Wait there is more. So I close cmd and reopen, then type: python hello.py and it says 'can't open file 'hello.py' [Errno 2] no such file or directory.' This is maddening. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where is your python file located on your computer?

Comment: It looks like it is on my hard drive in my Mu text editor folder

Comment: It would be super helpful if you could post the content of your hello.py and also the error messages you get when you do 'python hello.py'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, invalid syntax means there is a problem with your code. It opened the file just fine the first time you did it. If you want help with this, you'll need to post your code.

The second problem is probably because the file is in a specific folder, and you weren't in it. For example:

```
 - ~/ #The command line starts here
   - documents/
   - programming/
     - hello.py >This is where your file is
```

If you try to run `python hello.py` while in the home folder, it won't work because hello.py isn't in that folder. You have to go into the folder where it is.

Once you know which folders it's in (you can see a list of folders with `ls` on mac and `dir` on windows), you can go into that folder with `cd folder_name`. When you can type `ls` or `dir` and it one of the items is `hello.py`, then run `python hello.py`

Please note that the folder system I showed above is a guess - I have absolutely no idea where your file is.

Answer (score 1):

When you type "python" in the command line, you enter the **Python Interactive Shell**. This means that you are able to type python code and execute it. You know you are in the **Python Interactive Shell** when you see `>>>` at the start of the line. It is saying "invalid syntax" because you are trying to run `python hello.py` in the **Python Interactive Shell**. You can type `quit()` and hit enter to exit the shell.

Your second issue is happening because you don't specify the directory in which the python file is located. For example, let's say your python script, `hello.py`, is saved on your Desktop. You need to utilize the `cd` command, which is short for **change directory**.

```
cd Desktop
```

will change your current working directory to the Desktop. If your file is located in the Desktop, you can then type

```
python hello.py
```

and your script will run.